# Typescript generic return value inference issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

I'm not sure if this is a bug in TS or something they'd consider an unsupported feature. MVE:

```
interface ColumnOptions<R> {
  valueFormatter(params: R): string;
  valueGetter(params: string): R;
}

const getColumn = function<R>(options: ColumnOptions<R>) {};

getColumn({
  valueFormatter: params => 'hello',
  valueGetter: params => ({
    nr: 1,
    str: 'hello',
  }),
});
```

This is for an Ag-grid column definition and the goal is to infer that the parameter of `valueFormatter` comes from the return type of `valueGetter`. The parameter of `valueFormatter` (R) is inferred as `unknown` in the above case, but if I explicitly type or remove the parameter of `valueGetter`, like this:

```
getColumn({
  valueFormatter: params => 'hello',
  valueGetter: () => ({
    nr: 1,
    str: 'hello',
  }),
});
```

it infers R properly. This is what leads me to assume it may be a bug in TS, but maybe it's just unsupported and I didn't wanna open an issue on GitHub if that's the case. Tested with TS 3.8, 3.7, 3.5 and 3.0

Comment: I think `params` is `any` in the first case, and thus `valueGetter(params: string): R` does not match `valueGetter(params: any): infer`

Comment: If i don't explicitly type the `valueGetter` declaration, it infers the parameter's type correctly as string, from `ColumnOptions`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, your code creates a circular depending couple.

`R` can be inferred from either one of the functions as a **solid, instanced type**, then be used as a reference to deduce the function signature of the other one, if it’s incomplete or unknown.

But for that to work, you need to provide at least one solid type first, to break the circle. That’s what happen when you remove `param` from `valueGetter`, cus you cancel the request for TS to deduce the type of param, rendering `valueGetter` function a complete solid type.  Thus the return type can be used as a inferred type for `R`.

Below will also work, if you provide explicit type for `params: string`

```
getColumn({
  valueFormatter: params => 'hello',
  valueGetter: (params: string) => ({
    nr: 1,
    str: 'hello',
  }),
});
```